# StackOverflowException even after increasing the stack size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# WinForm application which I am running with x86 mode. It works great with x86 mode. the problem occurs when I run this application with Any CPU mode. I get the below mentioned error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in XXXXXX.dll

I know this could be caused by infinite loops and what not but the same error should occur in the x86 mode in that case. I know this is not because of infinite iterations. It has something to do with stack overflow.

After doing some research I increased the stack size with Editbin

from

> Editbin.exe /Stack:14000000 "$(TargetDir)MyProject.exe"

to

> Editbin.exe /Stack:14000000 "$(TargetDir)MyProject.exe"

Any idea what could be the cause and what directions should I go in to?

Comment: Is `XXXXXX.dll` your dll or a reference?

Comment: You should debug the problem instead of trying to patch it.  Specifically, look at that code and trace it to see what is really happening.  Patching something by simply increasing a stack size is usually a bad idea.  The cause of a stack overflow error is either really deep recursion or it's going off to infinity.

Comment: What does the exception stack trace look like?

Comment: I revised your question, but I cannot see what's the difference between `14000000` and `14000000`.

Answer (score 37):

> My bathtub is overflowing.

Try getting a bigger bathtub.

> OK, I did that. My bathtub is still overflowing.

Try getting an even bigger bathtub.

> OK, it's still overflowing!  I have a huge bathtub but it is still overflowing!

---

Getting a bigger bathtub doesn't help if the problem is that the drain is plugged and the faucet is on.

Your problem is likely that your program is attempting to consume an *infinite* amount of stack. Making the stack bigger won't help.

> I know this could be because of infinite loops and what not but the same error should occur in the x86 mode in that case.

This statement is false. There is no requirement that the same error occur.

> Why is it different depending on whether or not I'm targetting a particular cpu?

The jitter can generate different code in different scenarios, and sometimes can generate code that turns infinite recursions into infinite loops. Those won't consume infinite stack, but they will run forever.

> Suppose for the sake of argument that there is no unbounded recursion.

Then it is possible that there is a very *large* recursion. Since 64 bit code can up more stack space than equivalent 32 bit code, large recursions can cause out-of-stack errors to occur earlier.

In that case, making the stack larger is a bad idea. Instead, find the deeply recursive algorithm and make it into an iterative algorithm.

Comment: Having changed a deeply recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm with explicit stack for this exact reason, I can only say that this is a really sucky solution. Recursion is _the_ natural way to structure some algorithms, and this particular algorithm's readability got _completely destroyed_ (not to mention it became slower). I'd rather the stack could be "stretchy", just like normal allocations which are basically unbounded.

Comment: @romkyns: I agree that the iterative solution is often far less elegant. What if you used "await" to make the compiler do the work for you?

Answer (score 8):

The reason is infinite recursion. Attach a debugger and look at the stack trace when exception occurs.

Comment: Then it would also crash in x86 mode.

Comment: @Guffa: Is it *guaranteed* to do so?  Can the jitter, for example, decide to do a tail recursive optimization in one case but not the other?

Comment: @EricLippert: Then it would just lock up instead of crashing.

Comment: @Guffa: What if the overflow is on a low-priority background thread?

Comment: @EricLippert: Then the application would not work great. There would be something missing.

Comment: @Guffa: The program is known to throw unhandled out-of-stack exceptions. Reasoning about its correctness is a non-starter; we know that it is not correct. If sometimes its non-correctness manifests as reasonable behaviour that is not evidence that there are no unbounded recursions. A good assumption given the reported symptoms is that the program is buggy and there are sometimes unbounded recursions.

Comment: @EricLippert: What is your point? That the reason has to be infinite recursion? Why?

Comment: @Guffa: My point is that *we don't know what the cause of the problem is*. A reasonable hypothesis given the thin evidence presented is that there is an unbounded recursion on some code path. There is some extremely weak evidence *against* that hypothesis; we should not treat that weak evidence as though it were strong evidence. There are plenty of ways this could be an unbounded recursion; the fact that it does not consistently repro in some scenarios is not good enough evidence to discount that hypothesis.

Comment: @EricLippert: How does that tell you that it has to be infinite recursion?

Comment: @Guffa: It doesn't. That is a reasonable working hypothesis to be investigated, not a conclusion.

Comment: @EricLippert: So you are saying that it's likely that it's infinite recursion, because it doens't crash in x86 mode? That makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @Guffa: No, I'm saying that it's likely to be an infinite recursion *despite* the fact that it doesn't crash in x86. Any time you see an out of stack it's highly likely to be an unbounded recursion. That it does not repro consistently tells me very little; we already know the program is buggy. The flaky repro could be due to any of a million factors.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you are getting a stack overflow is simply because you are using too much of the stack.

The reason that you are only getting it in x64 mode and not x86 mode, is most likely because the programs uses more stack space in x64 mode because references take up more space. That you don't get it in x86 mode is just luck, you simply don't use quite enough stack space for it to run out under those specific circumstances.

The solution is to find out what it is in your program that uses so much stack space. You should look for things like recursive functions that run too many levels deep. A well implemented recursive function would use something like 10 or 100 levels of recursion, but if you are using recursion wrong you could perhaps have 10000000 levels of recursion, which would use a lot of stack space.

Answer (score 2):

Can You view the stack trace?

You can read up this property: Environment.StackTrace.

If the stacktrace exceded a specific threshold that you preset, you can return the function.
You can also try to replace some recursive functions with loops. (StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block if .net 2.0 and above)